# Problem in initiating i2c driver module for bmp180 i2c based sensor at kernel level

Tags: pi-3b+, i2c, kernel, driver, device-tree

For leaning purpose i am writing a i2c client kernel module for bmp180 pressure sensor.

My kernel code is ->

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

#define I2C_DEVICE_NAME     "bmp180"

static unsigned int major; /* major number for device */
static unsigned int minor = 0;
static struct class *bmp180_class;

struct my_dev {
    unsigned char *data;
    struct i2c_client *client;
    struct mutex bmp180_mutex;
    int current_pointer;
    struct cdev bmp180_cdev;
 };


 int bmp180_open(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp)
 {
  pr_info("Someone tried to open me\n");
  return 0;
 }

 int bmp180_release(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp)
 {
  pr_info("Someone closed me\n");
  return 0;
 }

 ssize_t bmp180_read (struct file *filp, char __user * buf, size_t count,
                              loff_t * offset)
 {
  pr_info("Nothing to read guy\n");
  return 0;
 }

 ssize_t bmp180_write(struct file * filp, const char __user * buf, size_t count,
                            loff_t * offset)
{
  pr_info("Can't accept any data guy\n");
  return count;
}

struct file_operations bmp180_fops = {
.owner      =    THIS_MODULE,
.open       =       bmp180_open,
.release    =    bmp180_release,
.read       =       bmp180_read,
.write      =      bmp180_write,
};

static const struct of_device_id bmp180_ids[] = {
{ .compatible = "bosch,bmp180", },
{ /* sentinel */ }
};


 static int bmp180_probe (struct i2c_client *client,
            const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
  struct device *bmp180_device;
  struct my_dev *bmp180_dev = NULL;
  int error;
  dev_t devt = 0;

  /* Get a range of minor numbers (starting with 0) to work with */
  error = alloc_chrdev_region(&devt, 0, 1, I2C_DEVICE_NAME);
  if (error < 0) {
    pr_err("Can't get major number\n");
    return error;
  }
  major = MAJOR(devt);
  pr_info("BMP180 major number = %d\n",major);

  /* Create device class, visible in /sys/class */
  bmp180_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "bmp180_char_class");
  if (IS_ERR(bmp180_class)) {
    pr_err("Error creating sdma test module class.\n");
    error=PTR_ERR(bmp180_class);
    goto fail;
  }

  bmp180_dev = (struct my_dev *)kzalloc(sizeof(struct my_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
  if (bmp180_dev == NULL) {
    error = -ENOMEM;
    goto fail;
  }

  bmp180_dev->data = NULL;
  bmp180_dev->client = client;
  bmp180_dev->current_pointer = 0;
  mutex_init(&bmp180_dev->bmp180_mutex);

  /* Initialize the char device and tie a file_operations to it */
  cdev_init(&bmp180_dev->bmp180_cdev, &bmp180_fops);
  bmp180_dev->bmp180_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
  /* Now make the device live for the users to access */
  error=cdev_add(&bmp180_dev->bmp180_cdev, devt, 1);


  if (error){
      pr_err("Error while trying to add %s", I2C_DEVICE_NAME);
      goto fail;
   }


   bmp180_device = device_create(bmp180_class,
                            NULL,   /* no parent device */
                            devt,    /* associated dev_t */
                            NULL,   /* no additional data */
                            I2C_DEVICE_NAME);  /* device name */

   if (IS_ERR(bmp180_device)) {
    pr_err("Error creating sdma test class device.\n");
    class_destroy(bmp180_class);
    cdev_del(&bmp180_dev->bmp180_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(devt, 1);
    return -1;
   }

   i2c_set_clientdata(client, bmp180_dev);
   pr_info("bmp180 char module loaded\n");
   return 0;

  fail:
    if(bmp180_class != NULL){
    device_destroy(bmp180_class, MKDEV(major, minor));
    class_destroy(bmp180_class);
  }
  if (bmp180_dev != NULL)
    kfree(bmp180_dev);
  return error;
  }  

static int bmp180_remove(struct i2c_client *client)
{

  struct my_dev *bmp180_device = i2c_get_clientdata(client);
  device_destroy(bmp180_class, MKDEV(major, 0));

  kfree(bmp180_device->data);
  mutex_destroy(&bmp180_device->bmp180_mutex);
  kfree(bmp180_device);
  class_destroy(bmp180_class);
  unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(major, 0), 1);

  pr_info("bmp180 char module Unloaded\n");
  return 0;
}

static const struct i2c_device_id bmp180_id[] = {
 {"bmp180", 0},
 {},
  };

  MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, bmp180_id);
  static struct i2c_driver bmp180_i2c_driver = {

    .driver     = {
    .name     = "bmp180",
    .owner    = THIS_MODULE,
    .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(bmp180_ids),
  },
   .probe      = bmp180_probe,
   .remove     = bmp180_remove,
  .id_table   = bmp180_id,
   };
   module_i2c_driver(bmp180_i2c_driver);
   MODULE_AUTHOR("Prateek Singh <prateeksingh22@hotmail.com>");
   MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Added device on device tree at I2C0 bus in bcm2835-rpi-b-plus.dts by following method ->

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
   /dts-v1/;
   #include "bcm2835.dtsi"
   #include "bcm2835-rpi.dtsi"
   #include "bcm283x-rpi-smsc9514.dtsi"
   #include "bcm283x-rpi-usb-host.dtsi"
   #include "bcm283x-rpi-csi1-2lane.dtsi"
 / {
   compatible = "raspberrypi,model-b-plus", "brcm,bcm2835";
   model = "Raspberry Pi Model B+";

   leds {
    act {
        gpios = <&gpio 47 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    };

    pwr {
        label = "PWR";
        gpios = <&gpio 35 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        default-state = "keep";
        linux,default-trigger = "default-on";
      };
   };
  };

&gpio {
/*
 * Taken from Raspberry-Pi-B-Plus-V1.2-Schematics.pdf
 * RPI-BPLUS sheet 1
 *
 * Legend:
 * "NC" = not connected (no rail from the SoC)
 * "FOO" = GPIO line named "FOO" on the schematic
 * "FOO_N" = GPIO line named "FOO" on schematic, active low
 */
gpio-line-names = "SDA0",
          "SCL0",
          "SDA1",
          "SCL1",
          "GPIO_GCLK",
          "GPIO5",
          "GPIO6",
          "SPI_CE1_N",
          "SPI_CE0_N",
          "SPI_MISO",
          "SPI_MOSI",
          "SPI_SCLK",
          "GPIO12",
          "GPIO13",
          /* Serial port */
          "TXD0",
          "RXD0",
          "GPIO16",
          "GPIO17",
          "GPIO18",
          "GPIO19",
          "GPIO20",
          "GPIO21",
          "GPIO22",
          "GPIO23",
          "GPIO24",
          "GPIO25",
          "GPIO26",
          "GPIO27",
          "SDA0",
          "SCL0",
          "NC", /* GPIO30 */
          "LAN_RUN", /* GPIO31 */
          "CAM_GPIO1", /* GPIO32 */
          "NC", /* GPIO33 */
          "NC", /* GPIO34 */
          "PWR_LOW_N", /* GPIO35 */
          "NC", /* GPIO36 */
          "NC", /* GPIO37 */
          "USB_LIMIT", /* GPIO38 */
          "NC", /* GPIO39 */
          "PWM0_OUT", /* GPIO40 */
          "CAM_GPIO0", /* GPIO41 */
          "NC", /* GPIO42 */
          "NC", /* GPIO43 */
          "ETHCLK", /* GPIO44 */
          "PWM1_OUT", /* GPIO45 */
          "HDMI_HPD_N",
          "STATUS_LED",
          /* Used by SD Card */
          "SD_CLK_R",
          "SD_CMD_R",
          "SD_DATA0_R",
          "SD_DATA1_R",
          "SD_DATA2_R",
          "SD_DATA3_R";

pinctrl-0 = <&gpioout &alt0 &i2s_alt0>;

   /* I2S interface */
   i2s_alt0: i2s_alt0 {
       brcm,pins = <18 19 20 21>;
      brcm,function = <BCM2835_FSEL_ALT0>;
     };
 };

   &hdmi {
     hpd-gpios = <&gpio 46 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
     power-domains = <&power RPI_POWER_DOMAIN_HDMI>;
     status = "okay";
     };

   &pwm {
     pinctrl-names = "default";
     pinctrl-0 = <&pwm0_gpio40 &pwm1_gpio45>;
     status = "okay";
     };

   &sdhost {
     pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&sdhost_gpio48>;
    bus-width = <4>;
    status = "okay";
    };

  &uart0 {
   pinctrl-names = "default";
   pinctrl-0 = <&uart0_gpio14>;
   status = "okay";
     };
  &i2c0 {

   pinctrl-names = "default";
   pinctrl-0    =   <&i2c0_gpio0>;
   status = "okay";
   clock-frequency = <4000000>;

   presure-sensor@77 {
   compatible   = "bosch,bmp180";
   reg = <0x77>;
    };
  };
```

All this i am implementing in rpi 3 b plus and able to build kernel code without any error. But after attaching device bmp180 at gpio 2 & 3 , I loaded module by insmod but its not going inside probe method as i am not getting any print present in probe method.

Could anybody tell me what i am missing by reviewing the above code and device tree.